# Monero directory vs .bitmonero lmdb

Tags: monerod, daemon, synchronization, full-node, linux

- I have two folders, ~/monero and ~/.bitmonero
- In ~/monero/'~'/monero/.monero/lmdb (180gb~ data.mdb) with a recent file date, means it's being used and updated
- In ~/.bitmonero there's ~/.bitmonero/lmdb (data.mdb = 1.8gb) but also ~/.bitmonero/'~'/monero/.monero/lmdb (data.mdb = 59mb), both have a small size, and an old date
- Everything in the ~/.bitmonero directory has a very old date, meaning it's not being modified
- If I rename/delete the ~/.bitmonero directory, the node starts syncing from 0, and when I return the original one, it starts syncing normally again from last block
- log file inside ~/.bitmonero is also not being updated

My questions:

1. Is this normal behavior? If not, how do I fix this without losing sync progress?
2. I need to have a config file, but it seems config file inside ~/.bitmonero is not being used (or how do I check if it's being used?), what now? I want to run this as a public node